# Make one cell editable in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I've got a datagrid view with the property of readonly = true; But i want to set some cells editable, i try to do this with the next code:

```
this.dgvNoCargadas.Rows[index].Cells[columns].ReadOnly = false;
```

But i can't modify the grid, someone had any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first remove dgv readonly true
and then

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
  {
      if (condition for true)
      {
          row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
      }
      else (condition for false)
      {
          row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: This works, if I put my datagridview in readOnly = true; and then modify the cells with row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false; it works but why it works here and no when i do the opposite?

Comment: Because when you make dgv readonly true it's not check child property means cell

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
dgvNoCargadas[columns, index].ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: No mate this didn't work, and it's the same i try but with diferent sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify each cell within the column as read only where the cell value is not equal to null or String.Empty. This will allow the user to edit those cells that are blank and protect your data.

Just loop through the DataGridViewRow's :-

```
Foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
   If(!row.Cells[2].Value.Equals(null) || !row.Cells[2].Value.Equals(String.Empty))
     {
        row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        row.Cells('Cellnumber').ReadOnly = False
    Next
```